# How to best model an 'unlimited' range, 'no limit', etc without using conditionals

Tags: php, if-statement, range, limit

Let's assume my application creates a list of products, depending on their respective price and amount of 1-star ratings they have. So it needs two parameters:

-A price-range, ussually modelled as a tuple/array with two int entries/or whatever else there is.

-A limit of how many 1-star ratings there can be. Example: If there is a limit of 5 1star ratings, products with 8 1star ratings won't get displayed.

Now, there's still the option of having no limit at all, and display products of all prices, which obviously affects the query to the database. To implement such a limit, I've often simply used if-conditionals: If the range is between 0 and 0,show all. If the limit is -1,remove the limit.

Thing is, this is ugly.

How would one properly implement the concept of no limit?

For the record, I'm coding a web app with PHP, using a MySQL database.

Comment: No limit is discouraged. It can lead to very slow queries. Using '<' or '>' with 'LIMIT' in Sql query plus pagination should work for you. The idea is to lower the burden on memory and use cache to speed up the requests and queries.

Comment: Ugliness is not a very useful quality metric. Post your existing code on codereview if you want some pointers for improving its structure

Comment: @Nitin Actually, my bad. I shouldn't have used the word limit. I am using pagination - The word limit was meant in a way that I have a where clause that excludes any entries having a specific value over a specific limit (See productrange/ratings example above). If I now want to include all ratings, for example, I'd have to use if-conditionals OR set a very high value. Thus the question if there's a prettier way to achieve that.

Comment: @Steve I will once I get back to my computer :)

Comment: Ok, @ reply me a link to the question when you post it ant ill take a look